# CSS Background Image is not showing ,although proper path and naming is correct

Tags: css, image

I have tried everything. This is my first attempt at building a website and deploying it.
Any Help is appreciate it.
On my local machine it works, but as soon i went to  upload my files to deploy the website, the image is not showing:

This is the path :../img/gallery/1111.jpg

Here is my code:

.fixed-light {

```
  background-image: url(../img/gallery/1111.jpg);
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
```

}

[General Directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YZvFJ.png)

[IMGs directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DXWqr.png)

Comment: Are you added css internal or external? if external , path of css file comment below.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes we need to declare first a path for our assets, it depends on what type of backend framework you are using.

Comment: are you using a hosting site or what?

Comment: I have no experience in webhosting sites but, have you ever tried to declare the path using complete path? ex: "/public_html/your_path"

Answer (score 0):

When you upload your website files on real you have to work more than often. For example, in nodejs if you have to use any other files rather than project files like image, audio, video you have to first serve files as static so here it can be possible that u have served files as normal and then it doesn't recognize. Hope this helps! By the way, before  using any framework or hosting site first know completely about it follow 3 or 4 tutorials and then start development. One more possibility is there that u have linked js file in head, if yes then add defer like:- `<script defer src="file.js">` because the js link given in head tag executes before the page loads